# Using an IF statement to decide which where clause to execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working in SQL Server 2008. I'm trying to decide which `WHERE` statement to run based on an `IF` statement. That may not be the correct way to go about this, I'm honestly not sure. Here is my code so far:

```html
SELECT A.[ArTrnDetail].[Invoice]
      ,cast(A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] AS DATE) AS InvoiceDate
      ,A.[ArTrnDetail].[Branch]
      ,A.[ArTrnDetail].[Salesperson]
      ,rtrim(A.[ArTrnDetail].[Customer]) AS Customer
      ,rtrim(A.[ArTrnDetail].[StockCode]) AS StockCode
      ,A.[ArTrnDetail].[QtyInvoiced]
      ,A.[ArTrnDetail].[NetSalesValue]
      ,A.[ArTrnDetail].[SalesOrder]
      ,rtrim(A.[ArTrnDetail].[CustomerPoNumber]) AS CustomerPO
      ,cast(B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate] as DATE) AS EarliestDate
      ,DATEADD(year, 1, B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate]) as LatestDate
      ,A.[InvMaster].[Description]
      ,LEFT(A.[InvMaster].[UserField2], 3) AS SalesSeries
      ,DATEDIFF(DAY,B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate], @enddate) as DateDifference   
    FROM A.[ArTrnDetail]
    JOIN A.[InvMaster] ON A.[ArTrnDetail].StockCode
    = A.[InvMaster].[StockCode]
    JOIN B.[EarliestSalesSeries] ON A.[InvMaster].[UserField2]
    = B.[EarliestSalesSeries].SalesSeries
```

I've defined @firstYearDay in the beginning of the code, before SELECT.

I need this to happen:

IF LatestDate > @enddate then run this where clause:

```html
   WHERE (A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] between @firstYearDay and @enddate)
 AND (DATEDIFF(YEAR,B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate], @enddate) < 1)
```

ELSE IF LatestDate < @enddate then run this where clause:

```html
   WHERE (A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] between @firstYearDay and LatestDate)
 AND (DATEDIFF(YEAR, B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate], @firstYearDay) < 1)
```

If you need more info, let me know. I'm new to stackoverflow so please just ask! Thanks for the help.

Comment: With sql-server version tag, always add sql-server tag to give more exposure to your question.

Comment: Bad habits to kick: For the date range queries try to stay away from `BETWEEN`.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE WHEN` to do `IF` logic in `where` clause.

```
   WHERE A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] >= @firstYearDay 
   AND A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] < DATEADD(d, 1 MIN(LatestDate, @enddate))
AND (DATEDIFF(YEAR,B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate], CASE WHEN LatestDate > @endDate THEN @enddate ELSE @firstYearDay END) < 1)
```

For the first condition I used `min` instead of `CASE WHEN`. You can use `CASE WHEN` there also.

Comment: Anup,
This doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I'm having trouble following the logic you're using. Would you mind trying to explain?

Comment: Is it giving you error or it it not giving you the result as you expected?

Comment: It's giving the error: Incorrect syntax near 'min', I tried changing the min to 'case when' but it gives the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Comment: Instead of `LatestDate` you need to use `DATEADD(year, 1, B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate])`. The above code was to summarize how to implement `IF` logic in `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it working. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. My answer is as follows:

```html
WHERE   
    (A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] < @enddate
    and
    A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] 
    between @firstYearDay and DATEADD(year, 1, B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate])
    AND DATEDIFF(day, B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate], @firstYearDay) < 365)
    or
    (A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] > @enddate
    and
    A.[ArTrnDetail].[InvoiceDate] between @firstYearDay and @enddate)
    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY,B.[EarliestSalesSeries].[InvoiceDate], @enddate) < 365)
```